# How to configure Kafka to behave like a FiFo queue?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I am having a small problem and that is that I have to use kafka as a notification system to start flows of my application, everything is fine, but I would like to know if I can alter the order when there are unread messages in the queue.

Let me explain: When there are two or more messages in the topic, and the consumer reads them, read first, the last one that has entered, and I want it to read first, the first one that entered.

So I wanted to know if it is possible and if it is, that we have to change for it.

I am using the latest version of Spring Apache, and Kafka 2.5.0

ConsumerConfig:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    private static final String BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS = "";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "id");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }


    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

KafkaConsumer:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "Great_Topic")
    private void listen(String msg) {
        System.out.println("I've received: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Example:

In my producer I have sent the following messages in this order:

- Hello World 1
- Hello World 2

Output in consumer:

- Hello World 2
- Hello World 1

I want the output to have the same order as the input.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Wow, I was hoping it could be, I find it quite strange that something that seems so simple cannot be done in kafka. @sonus21

Comment: Some systems are designed to specific use cases, queues are meant to use a stacks.

Comment: In the example you've quoted, is that you *observed* behaviour, or your *desired* behaviour?

Comment: Example is observed behavior @RobinMoffatt

Comment: So a queue can only have that behavior from what I see. Thanks for explain that @sonus21

Comment: @XxTheZokoxX no, you're looking for a stack, I'm not aware of any stack but I can suggest you how to build one using Redis or another database, certainly this is not possible using Kafka.

Comment: The problem is that this is a defined development already, if I am honest in a not very effective way as you can see, and I could not add a database since that would imply costs, which I cannot decide @sonus21

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you consume from a topic you can opt to read from the beginning, and when you do so you get all the of the messages *in the order in which they were produced into the partition*.

If you have a single partition **you will get strict FIFO behaviour**.

If you have *multiple partitions* (as it looks like you have here) then you get FIFO within a partition, but across partitions it will be non-deterministic. Thus you could get the behaviour you show.

Comment: The problem occurs when the consumer is off, and the producer keeps sending messages, when I activate the message again, it does not have a FiFo behavior, it has a LiFo behavior

Comment: PartitionCount:3, ReplicationFactor:2, The topic, and the server were created by my company, so I don't know if I could change the configuration, probably not. @Robin Moffat

Answer (score 3):

Maybe to complement the answer made by `Robin Moffatt`.

When you have multiples partitions you need to make sure that your producers force the `FIFO` policy using `key message` of each record. For example:

you have two partitions:

If you try to send the message below without any key:

> Hello World 1
>
> Hello World 2

Kafka can deal with this way:

> Hello World 1 (can be stored in partition 1)
>
> Hello World 2 (can be stored in partition 2)

Now if you consume those messages you can not guarantee `FIFO` to this group of messages.

As `Robin Moffatt` mentioned the `FIFO` will be applied in each partition.

To make sure this `FIFO` policy to the same type of records your can set in the producer side the `KEY` and assign to those similar messages the same key. For Example:

If you try to send the message below `ADDING` a key. (Normally Kafka producers request contain the `topicName`, `key` and `message`). Example:

> topic= Great_Topic key= messageKey message: Hello World 1
>
> topic= Great_Topic key= messageKey message: Hello World 2

Now Kafka will guarantee that all your messages with the same key flows to the same partition.

Like This

> Hello World 1 (will can be stored in the partition 1)
>
> Hello World 2 (will can be stored in the partition 1)

In this case partition 2 will be empty or like this

> Hello World 1 (will can be stored in the partition 2)
>
> Hello World 2 (will can be stored in the partition 2)

In this case partition 1 will be empty.

Now if you run your Kafka consumer making sure that your are not consuming in an async way your application will behave as `FIFO`